# Does a project have to be created as a sprite kit or can the framework simply be added?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I am taking a step backwards to learn sprite kit for the 2D Games I'm making, as opposed to using UIKit. In all the tutorials I've gone through, they've created the new project as a Sprite-Kit as opposed to single-view. Just wondering if I'll have to recreate my games or if I can simply add the sprite kit framework to my existing project? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The framework can simply be added.

Check the [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW3) from Apple. Apple is creating their Sprite Kit's example from a Single View Application and then Apple is adding the Sprite Kit framework to the project.