# Using sprite kit in a single View application

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to use an image in a single view application. I have seen many tutorials but almost all are explain sprite kit by using a gaming requirements. But I just want to get a simple tutorial of add an image through sprite kit. If any one know then guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The framework can simply be added.

Check the [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW3) from Apple. Apple is creating their Sprite Kit's example from a Single View Application and then Apple is adding the Sprite Kit framework to the project.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22511895/2803660)